# DynamoDB - Create Table - IAM Policy - Not Authorised Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

**Objective :** IAM user should be allowed to create a DynamoDB table in N.Virginia region only.

**My IAM Policy attached to the IAM User:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CreateMyTable",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "sns:CreateTopic"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyOtherRegions",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-east-1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting following error: 
**Not Authorised**
[image]

Am i missing out on any policy here? Please suggest.

Comment: Instead of deny allow single region only

Comment: This worked for me.. Thank you.. however i did not understand the difference.. what is the difference?

Comment: By default, IAM users are not authorized to do anything. Your original policy only restricts some actions, not granting any permissions.